# Launching Google Chrome logs me out of Fedora 35

Tags: google-chrome, fedora

I'm running Fedora 35 on a Dell Precision 3541, dual booted with Windows 10. Total storage for the system is 1TB, the storage dedicated to Fedora is about 650 GB. The system has 16GB of RAM. The desktop is Gnome.

Whenever I try to launch Google Chrome, Chrome begins to load for a few seconds, then I get logged out of Fedora.

I tried reinstalling both Fedora 35 and Windows 10; the problem remains. Both OSes were reinstalled from the same media as the original installs.

When I ran:
`journalctl | grep error`,
lines such as:
`Dec 27 19:51:44 fedora kernel: BTRFS error (device sda10): bdev /dev/sda10 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 806, gen 0`
dominated the output.

The output of:
`mount | grep sda10`
is

```
/dev/sda10 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/root)
/dev/sda10 on /home type btrfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,compress=zstd:1,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/home)
```

Running:
`ls -a /dev/sda10`
outputs nothing.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome, with no effect.

Also, after I'd been having these problems for several days, the system firmware was updated. The updates had no visible effect on my issues.

ABRT reports that the failing component is gnome-shell.

I installed KDE Plasma and switched to it using switchdesk. The effect of this was to add new issues on top of the original one, which remained unaffected.

I reinstalled gnome-shell, and switched back to gnome.

I have two questions:

1. Does the "corrupt 806" in the output of journalctl above refer to a hardware or software error?
2. Can anyone point me to resources that will help me solve my issue(s)?

Many thanks in advance for your help or advice.

Comment: If someone feels there is a more appropriate place to ask this question, please let me know, and kindly suggest what that forum might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use old `/home/username`, best thing to do before adding it to newer installed GNU/Linux is to remove folder `~/.config`, `~/.local`, `~/.cache`, any `~/.bashrc*`, and any other dot files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the root of the issue, and a solution that fixes at least *some* of the problems I've been having.

My last Fedora installation was Fe33, and my user name was `userA`.

Before upgrading to Fe35, I backed up `/home` to an external drive.

Then I installed Fe35, and as it happens, used a *different* user name, `userB`.

Then I restored the contents of `/home`. :-(

This left me with thousands of text files, as well as environment variables, containing the path `/home/userA`. What a mess!

What I've done as a workaround is, in `/home`, run `sudo ln -s userB userA`.

That has solved a lot of problems; others might perhaps be fixed by updating environment variables, and removing and reinstalling programs, such as Chrome, which have not been working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but maybe you should update your BIOS first from Windows.

Download here: [Dell Precision 3541](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-id/product-support/product/precision-15-3541-laptop/drivers).